# Query that returns data for every Friday for 1 year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that contains the number of orders a company makes per day from a given vendor, along with other information. I want to write a query that returns the number of orders from a vendor along with other info for every Friday for 1 year - i have figured this out as follows:

```
with dt as 
( select next_day(trunc(add_months(sysdate,-12)) + 7*(level-1),'FRI') d 
  from dual connect by level <= 53 ) 
select * 
from dt, vendor where vendor.dt = dt.d
```

But, suppose there are 10 vendors in total; and on a given Friday, orders were placed only from 6 vendors. Then for the remaining 4 vendors, i want to re-run the query for a Thursday and so on. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the query you figured it out (number of orders from a vendor a long with other info every Friday)

Comment: @Hawk 
`with dt as 
(
     select
            next_day(trunc(add_months(sysdate,-12)) + 7*(level-1), 'FRI') d
     from
            dual
     connect by level <= 53
)
select *
from dt, vendor
where vendor.dt = dt.d
`

Comment: It is too undetermined terms. Do you want to get orders data for a week or for an every day of week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your tables' structures, so I'll show you an example how I would do it.
Say there is a table `orders`:

```
CREATE TABLE orders(
  vendor varchar2(100), order_date date
);
```

then the query for this table could be:

```
SELECT to_char( order_date, 'IW' ) as Week_nbr,
       vendor,
       count(*) As number_of_orders
FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
           max( order_date ) OVER (Partition by vendor, to_char( order_date, 'IW' )) 
                 As lastest_date_within_a_week
    FROM orders t
) xx
WHERE order_date = lastest_date_within_a_week
GROUP BY to_char( order_date, 'IW' ),
         vendor
ORDER BY 1,2
```

This line:

```
max( order_date ) OVER (Partition by vendor, to_char( order_date, 'IW' )) 
                     As lastest_date_within_a_week
```

is looking for a latest (oldest) orders' date within each week for each vendor. If a vendor has only 2 orders in a given week, one in Monday, and second in Thursday, then this function returns a date of Thurdsay.

And here:

```
WHERE order_date = lastest_date_within_a_week
```

we are taking vendor's orders only from last day in a week.
Then the query is doing a simple `GROUP BY week_nr, vendor` and a `COUNT(*)`

A working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/96df3/1

Comment: Looks like a good approach, but I think that IW weeks always end on a Sunday.

Comment: @David yes you are right, but it's only a matter of simple WHERE condition that filters out rows for Sandays and Saturdays, even a beginner can manage a problem like this, I belive.

Answer (score 0):

You can sum data for every single date showing the day of the week with `to_char(sysdate,'d')`. Then you wrap the query and sum for the max day of the week grouping by vendor, like this `sum(imp) keep (dense_rank last order by day_of_week)`.

Watch out for NLS. Day of week depends on it